# Why does Android app debug version remove wearable version

Tags: android, wear-os

I can make a release.apk (which contains wear + mobile) install this and I get both my wearable and Android mobile versions working.

Then, if i install a debug version of just the mobile app using Android Studio, the wear counterpart disappears.

I dont need to change the Wear version. How do i experiment with different debug version of the mobile whilst keeping the Wear version unchanged and installed.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you have trouble with this but it is clear in the documentation if you update your app version number you **MUST** update your version number of your wearable module:

from the docs:

> Ensure that both the wearable and handheld app modules have the same package name and version number.

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Just a side note here:

Debugging wearables can be tricky and take some time, make sure you give your wearable enough time for your app to show up. I have noticed on my Moto 360 it can be quite slow when running new debug builds, so my advice is just be patient with the process when using a real hardware device.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly about the signatures on the APKs.

First, the Wear system will only push the wearable APK from the handheld if it's signed with a release cert. It won't happen if either app is signed with a debug cert.

But as you know, in order to run a debug-signed APK, there can't be a release-signed APK with the same package name on the device. This means that, when you want to run your debug APK on the handheld, any release build of the same app gets uninstalled first. Android Studio will do this for you, if you agree at the confirmation dialog.

However, when that uninstall happens, the Wear system will also uninstall the companion wearable app. This is a normal part of its job, keeping handheld and wearable apps in sync. But this is the answer to your question of "Why does Android app debug version remove wearable version".

Note that, even if it didn't uninstall, you'd be left with a cert mismatch between APKs at this point (debug on the handheld, and release on the watch). Which would break any data communications between the two components; signatures have to match for the Message or Data APIs to deliver.

The answer to your second question, "How do i experiment with different debug version of the mobile whilst keeping the Wear version unchanged and installed", is this: You install a debug-signed version of your wearable app direct to the watch from Android Studio. You can then reinstall your (debug-signed) handheld app as many times as you need to without affecting the wearable component. The Wear system won't attempt to keep APKs synced if they're signed with debug certs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im signing my debug version with the same key as the release ones. Using Android Studio, there doesn't seem to be a way to adjust the signing of the Wear app. Could that be not signed properly?  otherwise I think i'm using the same key all the time.

Comment: Well, whatever technique you're using to sign the handheld APK (Build Variants, `signingConfigs`, or whatever) *should* also work on the wearable APK. But even if you do get that to work, it will also mean that the Wear system may try to re-push your wearable APK every time you reinstall on the handheld, which probably isn't a good idea. You're likely better off using a debug cert (for both) and handling the un/installs manually.

Comment: Hi. Using a debug version on both works as you've suggested. Also, perhaps it _does_ push regardless and you wind up with no Wear version when there isn't any in the debug only version, keys notwithstanding. thanks.